# How to initialize a parameter (belonging to the first stage model) in a two stage model, taking its value from second stage model?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, stochastic-programming, gams

I am working on a two stage approach in order to reduce the complexity of a scheduling model which is an NP-hard problem. I have to implement a while loop in order to repeat solving the models in case the solution achieved from the second stage model is not feasible for the first stage model.

The problem is that I need to use a parameter whose value realizes after solving the second stage model (that shows whether the solution of the second stage model is feasible for the first stage model or not). Therefore, I have to initialize the first stage model within which I have to use this parameter.

The hardness is where that the parameter is multi-dimensional, preventing me from initializing it by my own. This parameter is `SD(i,d,l,t)`. Moreover, I have to pass the values of the first stage variables into the parameters of the second stage model. It is like being stuck in an unsolvable loop :)

Here is a simplified scheme:

```
Parameter SD(i,t,d,l);

While (conditional statement, 


*****Initialize SD(i,t,d,l) from the second stage model*****
if( SD(i,t,d,l) GT 0,

****Add cut EQ to the first stage model and solve it****
MODEL First /OBJ1,EQ/;          
SOLVE First USING MIP MINIMIZING cost;      
);

 
else (
****Add cut EQ' to the first stage model and solve it****
MODEL First /OBJ1,EQ'/;          
SOLVE First USING MIP MINIMIZING cost; 
);

 **** Form the second stage model  ****
Model Second /OBJ2,eq1, eq3,.../;  
SOLVE Second USING MIP MINIMIZING cost;

);
```

Comment: @A.Omidi Hi, may I ask you to solve this question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have much experience with stochastic programming, but just as a point, what actually is the difference between both `solve` statements for the first stage? They seem to be the same!

Comment: One has EQ as its constraint and the other has EQ'  together other constraints same as  the other if statement.

Comment: Models and equations are declarative in GAMS, and they have to be before the loop. Parameters used in the model can be populated afterwards (inside the loop).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen  Thanks a lot for your attention. To be honest, I can not understand the terms being declarative and being populated afterwards. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Sorry. I'll drop the difficult words. *Models and equations have to be before the loop. We can assign values to parameters used in the model afterwards (inside the loop).*  Adding cuts to a model can be done in a similar way. See e.g. [stochbenders](https://www.amsterdamoptimization.com/pdf/stochbenders.pdf).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen  Thanks a lot. The implementation of the Benders decomposition would help me a lot.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen May I ask you to explain the solver option solvelink? I found something in the instructing book of GAMS and on the net but I can not follow them. I become confused reading them.  And what is the application of Dynamic set in your GAMS example? It take yes and no values but I dont know what do they mean.

Comment: Not really possible to answer in a comment. I suggest reading the documentation carefully. Sets can be debugged easily using the DISPLAY statement. SOLVELINK is usually just for performance of solves in a loop.